# Deserialized jsonObject gets updated, foreach then fails

Tags: c#, foreach, json.net

I have a json File that I deserialize with Newtonssoft Json.Net like this:

```
/* Get current config */
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Speaker>(
                      File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\speaker.json"));

dynamic jsonDevice = json.DeviceList;

/* Go through the List */
foreach (Tapi tapi in lvTapiSonos.Items)
{    
   foreach (var line in jsonDevice)
   {
      foreach (var l in line)
      {
         /* If not in List already, add it */
         if (l.Key != tapi.Name)
         {
            /* Add to Config */
           json.DeviceList.Add(new Dictionary<string, List<Device>>
           {
              {
                 tapi.Name,
                 new List<Device>
                 {
                    new Device
                    {
                       Volume = "5",
                       Ip = currentEditIp,
                       Name = currentEditName
                    }
                 }
              }
           });
        }
     }
  }
}
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cfg\\speaker.json", output);
```

Unfortunately that only works for the first `foreach` as I get an exception "The List has changed. Enumeration cannot be continued," (similar as I have it in german) in the line `foreach (var line in jsonDevice)`.

I understand this means, that the `jsonDevice` has been updated (it shows now one more item in debug), but since I assigned `jsonDevice` outside of the foreach, how is it updated? Having `foreach var line in json.DeviceList` produce and error seems logical as I update the json Object inside the foreach, but why does this still happen?

Any hint appreciated...

Comment: I guess it's created by reference, instead of value here:
dynamic jsonDevice = json.DeviceList;

Comment: It is indeed a reference Copy to the same allocation, thus causing an issue in the `foreach` loop modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove
>   items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.
>   If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a
>   for loop.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

As explained you can use for loop for your usecase. but if you call ToList() or ToArray you can get copy of items which can be use for iterate

```
dynamic jsonDevice = json.DeviceList.ToList();
```

Comment: Good point here's the source code of the `ToList`,

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44

Answer (score 1):

Following is the ilegal code here:

```
json.DeviceList.Add(new Dictionary<string, List<Device>>
```

> Why ?

In `foreach` you get an enumerator to the collection, which is `read-only forward moving`, you cannot change the original source inside the `foreach` loop. You are accessing the `jsonDevice`, which is a reference copy of `json.DeviceList` collection which is modified

> What to do:

Convert to `for` loop and access by index, then you can change any collection as you are accessing by index and not changing the original collection with an attached enumerator

> Or

Create a deep copy of the collection, creating a new object and copying all value members and deep copy for all reference type. You may override `Memberwiseclone` of the base object class